# How to retrieve a default-styled paragraph's font family and size?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to write a function that would remove the heading, but retain the font and size, of the current paragraph.

However, it seems that values for font family/size cannot be retrieved from paragraphs that have their default font, as set by the heading applied.

```
var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();  if (!cursor) return;
var ctext = cursor.getSurroundingText();
var para = ctext.asParagraph();
para.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1); // sets Arial 20
var text = ctext.asText();
var ff = text.getFontFamily();
var fs = text.getFontSize();
DocumentApp.getUi().alert(ff+" "+fs); // NULL NULL
```

I tried accessing the headers' fonts and sizes, to get at them this way, but Google App Script doesn't seem to expose those anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

A header's style attributes can be retrieved with `Body.getHeadingAttributes(paragraphHeading)`.

A paragraph's style attributes can be overridden at the character level. That's what `text.getFontFamily()` and `text.getFontSize()` are retrieving. But, since these attributes weren't overridden at the character level in your example, they came back as `null`, in which case it is necessary to fall back to the paragraph's heading's style definition.

I added the fall-back logic to your example:

```
var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();  if (!cursor) return;
var ctext = cursor.getSurroundingText();
var para = ctext.asParagraph();
para.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1); // sets Arial 20
var text = ctext.asText();
// Get heading attributes
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
var headingAtts = body.getHeadingAttributes(para.getHeading());
var ff = text.getFontFamily();
//  If not set, fall back to heading attributes
if (ff == null) ff = headingAtts[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY];
var fs = text.getFontSize();
//  If not set, fall back to heading attributes
if (fs == null) fs = headingAtts[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE];
DocumentApp.getUi().alert(ff+" "+fs); // Arial 20
```

Answer (score 0):

More of a confirmation that this cannot be done right now, I took a look at the Attributes object and even accessed them directly with the same result. As a workaround, since you know the defaults, you can store those as Objects and set them when conditions are met in the script:

```js
function resetHeadings() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

  // store an object with default object attributes you can apply later
  var defaults = {
    "Heading 1": {
      FONT_SIZE: 20,
      FONT_FAMILY: 'Arial',
    },
    "Heading 2": {
      FONT_SIZE: 16,
      FONT_FAMILY: 'Arial'
    }
  };

  var pars = body.getParagraphs();

  for(var i in pars) {
    var props = pars[i].getAttributes();
    if(props["HEADING"] == "Heading 1") {

      // reset the Heading to normal
      props[i].setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL);

      // Then, spoof with your stored defaults
      // You can chain .setAttributes() with the line above. Shown separate for clarity.
      props[i].setAttributes(defaults["Heading 1"]);
    }
  }
}
```

It's not perfect, but it'll get you the outcome you're describing. You could use a case/switch test for each heading rather than multiple if statements.